# Error:You must use the “set” method to update an entry

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, tudo bem ?

Estou com problemas na hora de enviar dados ao meu banco de dados. Estou tentando inserir dados no BD mas, ocorre o erro nesta linha :

```
$categoriaModel->set('nomecatego', $this->request->getPost('nomecatego'));
```

Minha classe Model :

```
        <?php namespace App\Models;
    
    use CodeIgniter\Model;
    
    class CategoriaModel extends Model{
        protected $table = 'categoria';
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        protected $allowedFields = ['nome'];
        protected $returnType = 'object';
    }
?>
```

Minha classe Controller :

```
        <?php namespace App\Controllers;
    
    
    class CategoriaController extends BaseController{
    
        
        public function index(){
            //bla bla
        }
    
        public function inserir(){
            $data['titulo'] = 'Inserir nova categoria';
            $data['acao'] = 'cadastrar';
            $data['msg'] = '';
    
            if($this->request->getMethod() === 'post'){
                $categoriaModel = new \App\Models\CategoriaModel();
                $categoriaModel->set('nomecatego', $this->request->getPost('nomecatego'));
    
                if($categoriaModel->insert()){
                    $data['msg'] = "Cadastro feito com sucesso!";
                }
                else{
                    $data['msg'] = "Cadastro não realizado!";
                }
        }
            echo View('categoria_view', $data);
        }
    
    
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de ter um erro parecido e que houve foi o falta do campo em $allowedFields.

Tente colocar

```
protected $allowedFields = ['nomecatego'];
```

Segundo a documentação do **[CodeIgniter 4](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#manual-model-creation)**:

> $allowedFields
>
> This array should be updated with the field names that can be set
> during save, insert, or update methods. Any field names other than
> these will be discarded. This helps to protect against just taking
> input from a form and throwing it all at the model, resulting in
> potential mass assignment vulnerabilities.

Então, os campos passados nessa variável serão os permitidos para executar as ações de insert, update, etc.

Espero ter ajudado